# See what pattern a Regex object was created with?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a Regex object created with the `new Regex(string pattern)` constructor, is there a way afterwards to see what pattern the regex object was created with?

I can't seem to be able to access the "pattern" string member in either the Regex or in `RegexOptions` objects.

Context: Reason I'm asking is I'm creating a few regex objects early on while initializing (patterns are stored in a config file), they then get passed to a different class to be used frequently. However, I also need to compare the pattern string to those stored in a SQL database at run-time.

I would prefer not having to pass a string with the pattern in addition to the regex object. I also feel that creating the object once at startup is not a bad idea since the regex will be reused hundreds of times?

Feel free to provide alternative advices.

Comment: `protected internal string pattern` That's **really** awkward...

Comment: @Andre Calil Hmm.. perhaps they wanted to keep the freedom of modifying the patterns internally for compatibility or optimization purposes.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

So, in the debugger hovering the cursor over a regex object was showing the pattern, so it had to be close. Turns out Regex.ToString() returns the pattern.

[ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.tostring.aspx): Returns the regular expression pattern that was passed into the Regex constructor.

Comment: Easiest solution. No need to create a whole new class.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't seem like you can do it like this, seeing as the [`Regex.Pattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.pattern.aspx) field is marked internal.

You are correct in saying that it's a good idea to create the object once and reuse it multiple times, but passing the string as another parameter might be your only option.

If you really want to avoid doing that, you could create a new class that inherits from Regex, and then sets a Pattern property in the constructor, as follows:

```
public class MyRegex : Regex
{
    public String Pattern {protected set; get;}
    public MyRegex(String Pattern) : Regex(Pattern)
    {
            this.Pattern = Pattern;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I like this suggestion!

Comment: This would appear unnecessary thanks to the answer provided by @mtone.